# Setting up multiple GPUs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi, gpu

I am very new to setting up multiple GPUs on my machine. I have an RTX 3070 ti and 2070 super. I am facing some issues and I was wondering if I could get some answers:

1. I can't connect my monitor to 3070 ti. It only works when I connect the HDMI to 2070 super. I tried following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787030/setting-the-default-gpu) steps but changing `device0` to `device1` doesn't help. Moreover, is there a way I can toggle between the two device's HDMI without changing the file?
2. I am guessing that because of this, I can't benchmark them together. I am using Unigine Heaven and it only detects 2070 super, unless I don't disconnect the GPU from the power supply, then it detects 3070 and runs benchmark on it.

DO let me know what's going on. I am planning to use them for ML and I don't want to be stuck with running the code on 1 GPU.

Kindly let me know.

Comment: Hi. My computer and motherboard support both the cards because when I disconnect one, the other starts working.

Comment: I have enough power supply. That I know because Micro Center helped with the supply. And they suggested a motherboard that will be compatible with the GPUs. I don't know if you know PyTorch python library. I ran an instance to see how many GPUs it is detecting and it detects both of them.

Comment: If the software you want to use can use both cards at the same time for the tasks you want to use them for then you should be good.  It may not work for all applications though, which is probably why you aren't able to use them both for displays and why they aren't coming up in the benchmarks

Comment: Hmm. Well, my motherboard has two PCIe 16 ports for this purpose, to attach two GPUs. Is there a way to diagnose this? What can I do to at least run both the HDMI ports?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll test more code to see if they are properly working.